# How to dynamic switch from a Theme to another using Nativescript?

Tags: angular

Noob here,

I'm building an App using **Angular + Nativescript**. Currently I'm looking to create a simple `Switcher` or `Button` able to change my Theme using custom variables like:
`border-radius`, `shadow` (true or false), `background-color`.

Using **Nativescript** I know I can create Dark and Light themes automatically using this code:

```
lightTheme() {
    Theme.setMode(Theme.Light);
}
darkTheme() {
    Theme.setMode(Theme.Dark);
}
```

I also know I can create `const` variables like:

```
.my-div {
   color: const(my_custom_color);
}
```

But I don't know how to combine these things.

How can I create a something like switching from one theme to another?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably I can't do this with Nativescript only but if I need Angular Theming logic, let me know.

Comment: No one help? :(